# orderByChild() dispatch many times

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I'm trying to make SectionList with data get from firebase. I used to create FlatList with the following code and it works perfect.

```
firebase.database().ref(`/restaurantes/${currentUser.uid}/dishes`)
 .on('value', snapshot => {
      dispatch({ type: DISHES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() })
  });
```

and I get an array with all results (dispatch is executed only one time)
I tried to get data ordered so it would be easy to manage. But when I tried the following code, dispatch was executed 1 time for each result, so my state gets only the last result.

```
firebase.database().ref(`/restaurantes/${currentUser.uid}/dishes`)
 .orderByChild("category")
 .on('child_added', snapshot => {
      dispatch({ type: DISHES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() })
  });
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new code is listening for `child_added`, which fires for each individual child node. The original code listens for `value`, which fires once for all combined results.

To get the original behavior in the order of category:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/restaurantes/${currentUser.uid}/dishes`)
 .orderByChild("category")
 .on('value', snapshot => {
      dispatch({ type: DISHES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() })
  });
```